# Optional nullable entity - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my seller class

```
public class Seller {

    private boolean isActive;
    private String name;
}
```

this is my main entity

```
public class Book {

    private Seller seller;

    //here,it must be nullable if Seller.isActive = false, if true notNullable
    //@ifnullifisActiveisfalse like that i want
    private String sellerDescription;

}
```

`@ifnullifisActiveisfalse` like that i want but i could not see such usage. I only saw about creating another validation and validation at controller or service layer.

But i want to do in entity class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cross field validation is what you are looking for.

Annotate the class you want to validate:

```
@DescriptionRequiredIfSellerIsActive
public class Book {

    private Seller seller;
    private String sellerDescription;
}
```

Create the annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {SellerDesctiptionValidator.class})
public @interface DescriptionRequiredIfSellerIsActive {

    String message() default "";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Impelent the validator:

```
public class SellerDesctiptionValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SellerDesctiptionValidator, Book> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Book book, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
         return !book.getSeller().isActive() || 
             (book.getSeller().isActive() && book.getSellerDescription() != null)
     }    
}
```

You are not restricted to use it only in the controller mappings. You can autowire the validator anywhere you need and invoke the validation manually like this:

```
@Autowire
SellerDesctiptionValidator validator;

validator.validate(book);
```

Comment: Do i need to add something to xml files?